# Redirection from one page to another without showing that file path in Routes.js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new in Reactjs and I'm using `Material-UI`, My question is I wanted to go from one page to another page using sidebar and in Material-UI for redirection, it's compulsory to show that page in the sidebar which I don't want.

```
var dashRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/Dashboard",
    restricted: true,
    name: "Dashboard",
    icon: DashboardIcon,
    component: VesselInfoPage,
    layout: "/admin"
  },
  {
    path: "/Add/",
    name: "Add",
    icon: Group,
    component: AddPage,
    layout: "/admin"
  }
];
```

In the above code If I want to go from Dashboard to Add page so for that it's necessary to show that page in routes.js file, which I don't want.

Comment: remove the path from route and use the suggested approach i mentioned below. you would need to push new route to history by calling this.props.history.push('/admin'). invoke this on button click or any desired action.

Answer (score 0):

In react you can always do programmatic navigation for that you would need to use history api.

here is sample for same

```
class Register extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = (user) => {
    saveUser(user).then(() =>
      this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
    ))
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**If you want to know that in deep detail read this**

The real workhorse of React Router is the History library. Under the hood, it’s what’s keeping track of session history for React Router. When a component is rendered by React Router, that component is passed three different props: location, match, and history. This history prop comes from the History library and has a ton of fancy properties on it related to routing. In this case, the one we’re interested in is history.push. What it does is it pushes a new entry into the history stack - aka redirecting the user to another route.

here is blog post which talks about that 
https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/